# Named entity removal from a bank email. I want to remove and collect name, account numbers, orgnization names

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am very new in NLP. please help me to solve below Named entity removal  from a bank email problem.
I want to remove and collect:-  names, account numbers, organization names and date for other task and after removing named entity, process rest of the email through NLP process.
I tried using spacy ('en_core_web_sm') module, but its wrongly detecting information such as  amount and account number as date, account type and sometimes greeting word such as 'Hello team' as  organization.

sample of mail is :- " Hello Team, please convert account 12345678911 to business account, my contact number to reach is  909-500-6000 and address is  Client academy aa-77-05-10, 12543. warm regards, vanica be denial.

code I am using:-

```
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm)
t=nlp(text)
for i in t.ents:
    print(i.text, i.label)
```

`output:- Hello Team ORG, 12345678911  Date, Business Account ORG, Vanica be Name, Denial Name, 12542 Date, 6000 cardinal`,

I want the out be like:

`output:-  12345678911  account number, Business Account  Account type, Vanica be denial Name, Client academy aa-77-05-10,12543 address, 909-500-6000 contact number`

Please share some example code or reference to deal up with this

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some entity patterns, since spacy do not know anything about account numbers. Even the phone formatting isn't valid in english/american formats, you need to add these patterns too. You need then to add these patterns using rule matching OR train using some annotated data.
You can also follow the guides about [linguistic features](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features) and [rule-based matching](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) if your cases do not go far from it.

Comment: HI, I have completed pre processing part, can you suggest me which word2vec pretrained model should i try first bank finance data, were we classifying in different request types, such as: passbook print request, statement request, monetary transactions